# Whitespace in xsl text transformation

Tags: xslt, xquery, marklogic

A XSLT with a `xsl:text` containing a single (or multiple) whitespace(s) is not printing the whitespace(s) in MarkLogic 9.0-9. See the following example:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

let $doc := 
  <doc>
    <foo>foo</foo>
    <bar>bar</bar>
  </doc>
let $xsl :=
  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                  version="2.0">
      <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no" />

      <xsl:template match="doc">
          <xsl:value-of select="foo"/>
          <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="bar"/>
      </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>

return xdmp:xslt-eval($xsl, $doc) = "foo bar"
```

This returns false. The result is "foobar". I actually expected "foo bar".
I also tried with `<xsl:text xml:space="preserve"> </xsl:text>` but this does not work either.

As a workaround I currently use  `<xsl:value-of select="' '"/>` which works fine but I am wondering if this is a bug? Using the same transformation and document in Saxon prints the whitespaces.

Comment: I see the same "failure" using only Saxon XQuery calling XPath 3.1's `transform` function at https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiQZDbq/2 so I think the problem is in the inline inclusion of XSLT code in XQuery and how XQuery handles white space in such element constructors. I need to dig in the XQuery spec to find out what explains it and whether there is an option to have a different parsing mode. On the XSLT 2 side simply doing `<xsl:value-of select="foo, bar"/>` should fix the simple test case independent of any XQuery element construction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For standard XQuery you should get what you want with

```
declare boundary-space preserve;
```

in the query prolog, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-boundary-space-decls and https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-whitespace.

Example is https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiQZDbq/4 doing

```
declare boundary-space preserve;

declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";
declare option output:method 'text';


let $doc := 
  <doc>
    <foo>foo</foo>
    <bar>bar</bar>
  </doc>
let $xsl :=
  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                  version="2.0">
      <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no" />

      <xsl:template match="doc">
          <xsl:value-of select="foo"/>
          <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="bar"/>
      </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>

return transform(map { 'source-node' : $doc, 'stylesheet-node' : $xsl })?output
```

returning `foo bar` while https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiQZDbq/2 without that declaration returns `foobar`.

I have not checked whether Marklogic supports that declaration or some proprietary similar way to change parsing treatment of whitespace in element constructors.

Comment: Great answer. Tested it with MarkLogic and it works. Thank you.

Comment: Just to be clear *why* this works: `xsl:text` is special in XSLT in that it preserves whitespace, but it isn't special in XQuery. The whitespace is being stripped as part of the semantics of the tree construction performed by XQuery, and it's gone by the time XSLT comes into action. The XQuery spec suggests `<xsl:text>{" "}</xsl:text>` as a way of forcing the element to have whitespace content irrespective of the boundary space policy.